# Bell State Density Operators in Continuous Systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator, functional-derivatives

My question is about how density operators work in continuous systems, specifically maximally entangled states. I've outlined the math below but the TLDR is:

1. Does it make sense to talk about the density operator of a continuous system?
2. If the answer to 1 is yes, can a continuous system have a maximally entangled Bell State?
3. Is it correct to use a functional derivative when manipulating continuous systems?

For a discrete system with Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ we define the density operator:

$$
\hat{\rho} = \sum_{i=0}^{dim{\left(\mathcal{H}\right)}}p_i |\psi_i><\psi_i|
$$
where $p_i$ is the probability /admixture of states obeying the constraint:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{dim{\left(\mathcal{H}\right)}}p_i = 1.
$$
The quantity I'm interested in is how 'mixed' the state is, which we quantify with $\mu = Tr\left(\hat{\rho}^2\right)$. For example a pure state would have $\mu = 1$ and a mixed state would have $\mu <1$. We can find the lowest value of $\mu$ by minimizing via a Lagrangian multiplier:

$$
\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial p_j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{dim{\left(\mathcal{H}\right)}}p_i^2 -\lambda\left[\sum_{i=0}^{dim{\left(\mathcal{H}\right)}}p_i -1\right]\right)
$$
which when all said and done yields:
$$
\mu_{\left(\text{minimum}\right)} = \frac{1}{dim{\left(\mathcal{H}\right)}}.
$$
If we check this manually for the $dim{\left(\mathcal{H}\right)}=2$ Bell State i.e. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|10>+|01>\right)$ we will get $\mu=\frac{1}{2}$as expected.

Now in the continous case, we define the density operator,
$$
\hat{\rho} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ \mathrm{d}x p(x) |x><x|
$$
with the constraint
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ \mathrm{d}x p(x) = 1. 
$$
We define the level of 'mixed-ness' in the equivalent way:
$$
\mu = Tr\left(\hat{\rho}^2\right) = \int \mathrm{d} x \ p(x)^2.
$$
We then try a similar minimization procedure to the discrete case:
$$
Tr\left(\hat{\rho}^2\right) = \int \mathrm{d} x \ p(x)^2 - \lambda\left(\int\mathrm{d}x \ p(x) - 1\right).
$$
This initially raised an issue as it wasn't obvious to me how to perform the differentiation with respect to the probability when it lives inside integrals. My idea was to employ the functional derivative as $p(x)$ is a function. For some function $A = A(p(x))$:
$$
\frac{\delta A}{\delta p(x)} = lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\frac{A\left(p(y)+\epsilon\delta(x-y)\right)-A(p(y))}{\epsilon}\right)
$$
which when applied to $\mu$ yields,
$$
p(x) = \frac{\lambda}{2} \  \forall x.
$$
This is a big issue though as we are subject to the constraint $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}xp(x)=1$. I can't seem to reconcile the probability norm. with the seemingly constant probability function. Does this break down because applying the functional derivative here is not correct? Or is the idea of a maximally entangled continous system not possible?

Besides the mathematical issue I also have a conceptual issue with this. We know that when in a Bell state, if we make an ideal projective measurement on variable, we gain perfect information about the others. For instance with the previous example

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|10>+|01>\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|1>_A\otimes|0>_B+|0>_A\otimes|1>_B\right)
$$

for $H=H_A\otimes H_B$. If I make a measurement on $H_A$ and collapse the state, I also collapse the state in $H_B$ completely. This would suggest in the continuous case that if I make an ideal projective measurement on one state I gain perfect information about an infinite number of states, which seems non-physical. Is there a way to reconcile this?

Comment: No density matrices exist with continuous spectrum: density matrices always have discrete spectrum since they are compact operators.